# News Feed Response parsing in iphone using Facebook Graph Api

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, facebook-graph-api, response

I am using Facebook Graph API...for fetching the data of news feed of the facebook profile..

and here is the response that i am getting in the console

```
    {
    application =         {
        id = 2309869772;
        name = Links;
    };
    "created_time" = "2011-02-10T09:44:27+0000";
    from =         {
        id = 1845195019;
        name = "Paritosh Raval";
    };
    icon = "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif";
    id = "1845195019_192144087475935";
    likes =         {
        count = 1;
        data =             (
                            {
                id = 1845195019;
                name = "Paritosh Raval";
            }
        );
    };
    link = "http://www.facebook.com/AMDAVAD";
    name = "once you live in AHMEDABAD u cannot live anywhere else in the world..";
    picture = "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203562_115963658443669_4129246_n.jpg";
    properties =         (
                    {
            name = Page;
            text = "21,803 people like this.";
        }
    );
    type = link;
    "updated_time" = "2011-02-10T09:44:27+0000";
},
    {
    application =         {
        id = 2392950137;
        name = Video;
    };
    "created_time" = "2011-02-02T04:18:22+0000";
    description = "must watch and explore :))";
    from =         {
        id = 1845195019;
        name = "Paritosh Raval";
    };
    icon = "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif";
    id = "1845195019_194836027209359";
    likes =         {
        count = 1;
        data =             (
                            {
                id = 100000701228096;
                name = "Bhargav Jani";
            }
        );
    };
    link = "http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=152586058110610&comments";
    name = "It Happens Only in....";
    "object_id" = 152586058110610;
    picture = "http://vthumb.ak.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-ak-snc4/50893_152586468110569_152586058110610_18299_1832_t.jpg";
    properties =         (
                    {
            name = Length;
            text = "0:54";
        }
    );
    source = "http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/cfs-ak-ash2/70137/56/152586058110610_53804.mp4?oh=481e53b824f6db8e3195fc9c0d07571d&oe=4DAFC300&__gda__=1303364352_7670272db65e93ec75dcaaed16b6d805";
    type = video;
    "updated_time" = "2011-02-02T04:18:22+0000";
}
```

And I want to show every data in the organized structure in the console. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

it's unclear what you exactly asking but I try to answer.

First of all you need to parse this response in the method
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result of [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

result can be a string, a NSArray if you have multiple results and NSDictionary

In you console output we can see NSDictionary with included arrays and dictionaries in it. 
I have little tutorial about it but it's on russian only and site is down today :( so i just copy one example from my article.

Let say we want to know what facebook user Likes

```
- (IBAction)getUserInfo:(id)sender {
  [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/likes" andDelegate:self];
}
```

if we try this Graph API response in browser or output to console we can see what this request returns. It returns dictionary with one and only key - "data" and corresponded array to this key. This array contents dictionary objects again with keys -
 «name»,"category","id","created_time". Dont forget request «user_likes» permission before.
So we have parsing method like that:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([result objectForKey:@"owner"]) {
        [self.label setText:@"Photo upload Success"];
    } else if ([result objectForKey:@"data"]){
        NSArray *likes = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *text=@"You don't like Steve";
        for (NSDictionary* mylike in likes) {
            NSString *mylikeName = [mylike objectForKey:@"name"];
            if ([mylikeName isEqualToString:@"Steve Jobs"]) {
                text=@"You like Steve";
                break;
            }
        }
        [self.label setText:text];
    }
};
```

You can parse you result same way and fill your object's variables and then use it to display information in TableView for example. good luck!

Comment: .Thanks..can can you give me the link of that site? I will also check it out on another day

Comment: there are no more parsing examples on this article. It's just begginer tutorial for using Facebook SDK. Anyway ... http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/macosxdev/116417