# how to check condition for parsed elements in iphone

Tags: iphone, json, parsing

from the Json parsing in my project I am getting these elements...

executing instruction:-

```
NSArray *feed3 = (NSArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"type"];  
NSLog(@" %@",feed3);
```

in console I am getting this

> (
>       status,
>       photo,
>       link,
>       video   )

Now I want to check condition for these elements..

like

```
if(type==staus){  
//do some thing  
}
```

how to do this in xcode?

Comment: What is your original JSON data?

Comment: here ..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712108/news-feed-response-parsing-in-iphone-using-facebook-graph-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming that `feed3` is the object returned by the JSON parser after having parsed the JSON data you listed in another question. In that case:

```
* the top level object is an array
* every element in the array is an object/dictionary representing news
* this object/dictionary contains the following keys:
  * application (object/dictionary with two keys: id, name)
    * id (number)
    * name (string)
  * created_time (string)
  * from (object/dictionary with two keys: id, name)
    * id (number)
    * name (string)
  * icon (string)
  * id (string)
  * likes (object/dictionary with two keys: count, data)
    * count (number)
    * data (array)
      * every element in the array is an object/dictionary
      * this object/dictionary has two keys (id, name)
        * id (number)
        * name (string)
  * link (string)
  * name (string)
  * picture (string)
  * properties (array of objects/dictionaries)
  * type (string)
  * updated_time (string)
```

When parsing JSON data, it’s **vital** to understand how data is organised. I suggest you always do the above whenever you have to parse JSON.

Since you’re interested in ‘type’, you need to follow this path:

- traverse the top level array of news

  - every element in the array is an object/Dictionary

    - this object/dictionary has a key called ‘type’

The following code should do the trick:

```
for (NSDictionary *news in feed3) {
    NSString *type = [news objectForKey:@"type"];

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
       …
    }
    else if ([type isEqualToString:@"photo"]) { 
       …
    }
    else if ([type isEqualToString:@"link"]) { 
       …
    }
    else if ([type isEqualToString:@"video"]) { 
       …
    }
}
```

Note that, in general, you should use `-objectForKey:` instead of `-valueForKey:`:

- `-objectForKey:` is a method declared in `NSDictionary` and it is used to obtain an object stored in the dictionary given the corresponding key.
- `-valueForKey:` is a KVC method and serves another purpose. In particular, it can return an array when you’re not expecting one!

Comment: hey..Bavarious...this is the great explaination I have ever got..since I am a new bie..please suggest me where can I learn such parsing stuffs..any good site or any book if you can suggest..Thanks very much...Accepted and Up :)

Comment: @rathodrc It’s essentially paying close attention to the data. When you have row JSON data, it’s useful to paste it on http://jsonlint.com — it’ll tell you if the data are valid and will format them in a way that makes it easy to understand what’s there.

Comment: @rathodrc But note that you’ve posted in that other question **is not** the original JSON data — it’s just the way `NSLog()` prints arrays and dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Check below

```
for(int index = 0 ; index < [feed3 count] ; index++)
{
    NSString* tempString = [feed3 objectAtIndex:index];

    if([tempString isEqualToString:@"status"]) 
    {
      //Get value for status from value array
    }
    else if([tempString isEqualToString:@"photo"]) 
    {
      //Get value for photo from value array
    }
    else if([tempString isEqualToString:@"link"]) 
    {
      //Get value for link from value array
    }
    else if([tempString isEqualToString:@"video"]) 
    {
      //Get value for video from value array
    }
}
```

Comment: Still won’t work. :-P The object returned by the JSON parser is an array comprised of dictionary objects.